# Building a Simple Menu With Perl

Tags: optimization, perl

I wrote a Perl script to implement a simple menu where you can call subroutines for each menu option.  I created a Menu class that can be used to create new menus and a print method that will start the menu.

Is there any way I could simplify this?

```
# Menu.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu;

use strict;
use warnings;

# Menu constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my $class       = shift;
    my (%args)      = @_;
    my $title       = $args{title};
    my $choices_ref = $args{choices};
    my $noexit      = $args{noexit};

    # Bless the menu object
    my $self = bless {
        title   => $title,
        choices => $choices_ref,
        noexit  => $noexit,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Print the menu
sub print {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my $self    = shift;
    my $title   =   $self->{title  };
    my @choices = @{$self->{choices}};
    my $noexit  =   $self->{noexit };

    # Print menu
    for (;;) {

        # Clear the screen
        system 'cls';

        # Print menu title
        print "========================================\n";
        print "    $title\n";
        print "========================================\n";

        # Print menu options
        my $counter = 0;
        for my $choice(@choices) {
            printf "%2d. %s\n", ++$counter, $choice->{text};
        }
        printf "%2d. %s\n", '0', 'Exit' unless $noexit;

        print "\n?: ";

        # Get user input
        chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);

        print "\n";

        # Process input
        if ($input =~ m/\d+/ && $input >= 1 && $input <= $counter) {
            return $choices[$input - 1]{code}->();
        } elsif ($input =~ m/\d+/ && !$input && !$noexit) {
            print "Exiting . . .\n";
            exit 0;
        } else {
            print "Invalid input.\n\n";
            system 'pause';
        }
    }
}

1;
```

I wrote up a quick test script to test the module:

```
# test.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Menu;

my $menu1;
my $menu2;

# define menu1 choices
my @menu1_choices = (
    { text => 'Choice1',
      code => sub { print "I did something!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Choice2',
      code => sub { print "I did something else!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Go to Menu2',
      code => sub { $menu2->print(); }},
);

# define menu2 choices
my @menu2_choices = (
    { text => 'Choice1',
      code => sub { print "I did something in menu 2!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Choice2',
      code => sub { print "I did something else in menu 2!\n"; }},
    { text => 'Go to Menu1',
      code => sub { $menu1->print(); }},
);

# Build menu1
$menu1 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu1',
    choices => \@menu1_choices,
);

# Build menu2
$menu2 = Menu->new(
    title   => 'Menu2',
    choices => \@menu2_choices,
);

# Print menu1
$menu1->print();
```

I feel like there must be a simpler, more elegant (or maybe just more pleasing to the eye) way to pass in the menu options rather than using an array of hashes, but I can't seem to figure out any better way to do it.

---

**EDIT:**

After some careful code reworking and making the menu items into their own object I was able to create a much cleaner interface for creating menus.  Here is my new code:

This is a test script showing an example of how to use the modules to build menus.

```
# test.pl

#!/usr/bin/perl

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Other use statements
use Menu;

# Create a menu object
my $menu = Menu->new();

# Add a menu item
$menu->add(
    'Test'  => sub { print "This is a test\n";  system 'pause'; },
    'Test2' => sub { print "This is a test2\n"; system 'pause'; },
    'Test3' => sub { print "This is a test3\n"; system 'pause'; },
);

# Allow the user to exit directly from the menu
$menu->exit(1);

# Disable a menu item
$menu->disable('Test2');
$menu->print();

# Do not allow the user to exit directly from the menu
$menu->exit(0);

# Enable a menu item
$menu->enable('Test2');
$menu->print();
```

The Menu.pm module is used to build menu objects.  These menu objects can contain multiple Menu::Item objects.  The objects are stored in an array so their order is preserved.

```
# Menu.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu;

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Other use statements
use Carp;
use Menu::Item;

# Menu constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($class, $title) = @_;

    # Define a default title
    if (!defined $title) {
        $title = 'MENU';
    }

    # Bless the Menu object
    my $self = bless {
        _title => $title,
        _items => [],
        _exit  => 0,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Title accessor method
sub title {
    my ($self, $title) = @_;
    $self->{_title} = $title if defined $title;
    return $self->{_title};
}

# Items accessor method
sub items {
    my ($self, $items) = @_;
    $self->{_items} = $items if defined $items;
    return $self->{_items};
}

# Exit accessor method
sub exit {
    my ($self, $exit) = @_;
    $self->{_exit} = $exit if defined $exit;
    return $self->{_exit};
}

# Add item(s) to the menu
sub add {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @add) = @_;
    croak 'add() requires name-action pairs' unless @add % 2 == 0;

    # Add new items
    while (@add) {
        my ($name, $action) = splice @add, 0, 2;

        # If the item already exists, remove it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                splice @{$self->{_items}}, $index, 1;
            }
        }

        # Add the item to the end of the menu
        my $item = Menu::Item->new($name, $action);
        push @{$self->{_items}}, $item;
    }

    return 0;
}

# Remove item(s) from the menu
sub remove {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @remove) = @_;

    # Remove items
    for my $name(@remove) {

        # If the item exists, remove it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                splice @{$self->{_items}}, $index, 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

# Disable item(s)
sub disable {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @disable) = @_;

    # Disable items
    for my $name(@disable) {

        # If the item exists, disable it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                $self->{_items}->[$index]->active(0);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

# Enable item(s)
sub enable {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self, @enable) = @_;

    # Disable items
    for my $name(@enable) {

        # If the item exists, enable it
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            if ($name eq $self->{_items}->[$index]->name()) {
                $self->{_items}->[$index]->active(1);
            }
        }
    }
}

# Print the menu
sub print {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($self) = @_;

    # Print the menu
    for (;;) {
        system 'cls';

        # Print the title
        print "========================================\n";
        print "    $self->{_title}\n";
        print "========================================\n";

        # Print menu items
        for my $index(0 .. $#{$self->{_items}}) {
            my $name   = $self->{_items}->[$index]->name();
            my $active = $self->{_items}->[$index]->active();
            if ($active) {
                printf "%2d. %s\n", $index + 1, $name;
            } else {
                print "\n";
            }
        }
        printf "%2d. %s\n", 0, 'Exit' if $self->{_exit};

        # Get user input
        print "\n?: ";
        chomp (my $input = <STDIN>);

        # Process user input
        if ($input =~ m/^\d+$/ && $input > 0 && $input <= scalar @{$self->{_items}}) {
            my $action = $self->{_items}->[$input - 1]->action();
            my $active = $self->{_items}->[$input - 1]->active();
            if ($active) {
                print "\n";
                return $action->();
            }
        } elsif ($input =~ m/^\d+$/ && $input == 0 && $self->{_exit}) {
            exit 0;
        }

        # Deal with invalid input
        print "\nInvalid input.\n\n";
        system 'pause';
    }
}

1;
```

The Item.pm Module must be stored in a subfolder called "Menu" In order for it to be referenced properly.  This module lets you create Menu::Item objects that contain a name and a subroutine reference.  These objects will be what the user selects from in the menu.

```
# Item.pm

#!/usr/bin/perl

package Menu::Item;

# Always use these
use strict;
use warnings;

# Menu::Item constructor
sub new {

    # Unpack input arguments
    my ($class, $name, $action) = @_;

    # Bless the Menu::Item object
    my $self = bless {
        _name   => $name,
        _action => $action,
        _active => 1,
    }, $class;

    return $self;
}

# Name accessor method
sub name {
    my ($self, $name) = @_;
    $self->{_name} = $name if defined $name;
    return $self->{_name};
}

# Action accessor method
sub action {
    my ($self, $action) = @_;
    $self->{_action} = $action if defined $action;
    return $self->{_action};
}

# Active accessor method
sub active {
    my ($self, $active) = @_;
    $self->{_active} = $active if defined $active;
    return $self->{_active};
}

1;
```

This design is a vast improvement over my previous design and makes creating menus much easier and cleaner.

Let me know what you think.

Any comments, thoughts, or improvement ideas?

Comment: BTW, you probably want `/^\d+$/`, because just `/\d+/` will match things like `"foo123bar"`

Comment: The modifier methods are a good call.  I still recommend a framework like Moo though.  Saves lots of typing and gives your class a more standard implementation.  For example, most module authors use a hash-key name the same as the attribute name, rather than with an underscore.  (not that the underscore is wrong, just less standard)

Comment: @MConrad I've seen it done both ways.  Adding the underscore just seems to discourage accessing the attributes without going through the accessor method. In a way it makes them a little more "private."  And unfortunately I only have access to the default modules that come with an install of ActivePerl so stuff like Moo isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making perl APIs convenient is a bit of an art form, and perl gives you a lot to work with.

If you just want to streamline your code a bit, you could make a convenience method for the common cases like this:

```
my $menu1= Menu->new_from_list(
  "Menu1",
  "Choice1"     => sub { print "I did something!\n"; },
  "Choice2"     => sub { print "I did something else!\n"; },
  "Go to Menu2" => sub { $menu2->print(); },
  "noexit"
);
```

Then the code in new_from_list() would take those arguments and build the proper attribute tree for new():

```
sub new_from_list {
  my $class= shift;
  my $title= shift;
  my @choices;
  my $noexit= 0;
  while (@_ > 1) {
    push @choices, { text => shift, code => shift };
  }
  if (@_) {
    if ($_[0] eq 'noexit') {
      $noexit= 1;
    }
    else {
      die "unknown final argument to new_from_list: $_[0]"
    }
  }
  return $class->new( title => $title, choices => \@choices, noexit => $noexit );
}
```

The new_from_list API can't be extended easily in the future, but that's ok because it just handles a common case, and you can fall back to the normal constructor any time you need to.

Also, for simplifying the code needed to define Menu class, consider using a framework like [Moo](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo).

```
package Menu;
use Moo;

has title   => ( is => 'rw', required => 1 );

has choices => ( is => 'rw', required => 1 );

# choices is an arrayref.  This convenience method returns it as a list
sub choices_list { @{ shift->choices } }

has noexit  => ( is => 'rw' );


sub print {
  my $self= shift;
  ...
  for my $choice ($self->choices_list) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have begun to develop Perl packages using `Moose`, which appears to be very similar to `Moo`.  I would guess it's the same thing just with more features judging by the name.  It definitely simplifies code writing though!

Comment: Moo is actually a simplified version of Moose, the purpose being to reduce the number of dependencies on other modules and the startup time.